# how to add android.manifest in my cordova project

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I have a problem installing ".apk" file that i generated to my device
I just discovered on StackOverflow that i have to set the version in android.manifest file of Cordova Project.
But i don't have any android.manifest!

1. how can add it?
2. where do i neet to put this file?
3. if yes where can i find a template to set all parameters?

> I have visual studio 2015 with Cordova installed  and in "add new
>   file" there is no android.manifest

Answer (score 0):

> I just discovered on StackOverflow that i have to set the version in android.manifest file of Cordova Project. But i don't have any android.manifest!

If you compile your project, you can find `AndroidManifest.xml` under `Project Folder\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml`. But it is not recommended modifying this file, because in cordova, in every compilation for android platform, this file will be overrided.

The recommended way is to double click `config.xml` file under your project folder and you will get something like below:

[image]

by "the Version" if you mean the SDK Version, then you should modify the Minimum/Maximum/Target API level.

If you mean the version of your app, then you should modify the value of Version Code.

After this, delete the app in your emulator/device, rebuild your project and run.

Comment: i read to update android.manifest to fix the error :"error parsing package" in my phone i have this problem when i want to try my .apk

Comment: There is no `android.manifest` file, there is only `AndroidManifest.xml` file, no matter for android native development or cordova. Please refer to [Android App Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). And in cordova you should edit `config.xml` file to make changes to `AndroidManifest.xml`.